# Shortcut to add throws declaration in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I can manually add throws declaration by using mouse(click on error and add throws).But am just wondering is there any shortcut in eclipse to do that without involving mouse. like **Ctrl+shift+o** does auto imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to `preference --> General--> keys` to set a hot key for the Command "Add throws declaration" .

Make sure to select `Editing Java Source` in When

[image]

Comment: it is working only when am on that error line. if i move around and use that shortcut it is not working